# Reset Radio Button State using Recycler View in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a problem using radio button inside a recycler view, the radio button works fine, but when I go back to the previous fragment, and go back to the fragment where the recyclerview is included, the radio button state is checked on the last item that I clicked, I want to reset the state of the radio button. Here's a screenshot of the example.

Here is where I navigate into a fragment that include the recyclerView for the first time : [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na3EG.png)

And here is when I clicked one of the choices, go back to the previous fragment, and go back to the fragment where the recyclerView is included : [Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diHBt.png)

Here is my code in fragment, adapter, and viewholder

Fragment :

```
private fun initializeRecyclerView(){
    val transactionTypeLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
    
    val list = TransactionType.values().toList()
    val transactionTypeAdapter = ManualMixTransactionTypeAdapter(list)
    binding?.recyclerViewTransactionType?.layoutManager = transactionTypeLayoutManager
    binding?.recyclerViewTransactionType?.adapter = transactionTypeAdapter

    transactionTypeAdapter.onTransactionTypeClicked = {
        viewModel.setTransactionType(it.name)
        Toast.makeText(context, "${it.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Adapter :

```
var onTransactionTypeClicked: ((TransactionType) -> Unit)? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TransactionTypeViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ViewholderTransactionTypeBinding = ViewholderTransactionTypeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
    return TransactionTypeViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TransactionTypeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.rbTransactionType.setText(transactionType[position].key)
    holder.render(
        data = transactionType[position],
        dataIndex = position,
        adapterListener = {
            val oldTransactionType = transactionType.find { transactionType -> transactionType.isItemSelected }

            oldTransactionType?.apply { isItemSelected = false }

            val oldPosition = transactionType.indexOf(oldTransactionType)

            notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)
        },
        updateListener = { newPosition -> notifyItemChanged(newPosition)},
        clickListener = onTransactionTypeClicked
    )
}
```

Viewholder :

```
fun render(
    data: TransactionType,
    dataIndex: Int,
    adapterListener: (() -> Unit),
    updateListener: ((Int) -> Unit),
    clickListener: ((TransactionType) -> Unit)?
) {
    val onClickListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {

        adapterListener.invoke()

        data.isItemSelected = true

        updateListener.invoke(dataIndex)

        clickListener?.invoke(data)
    }

    binding.vhTransactionType.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
    binding.rbTransactionType.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)

    binding.rbTransactionType.isChecked = data.isItemSelected
}
```

Any solution would be great, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you remove this line inside render function, your code would behave the way you’re expecting it: `binding.rbTransactionType.isChecked = data.isItemSelected`

Comment: it's not working, if i delete that line of code, it allows me to check all the radio button @JeelVankhede

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the selection on the radio button before setting its correct value.

I will use a java example to explain the concept.

```
holder.radioGroup.clearCheck()
```

This way, the `RadioGroup` clears its selection, ready to receive an input that will trigger the correct `RadioButton` as checked.

But you need to be aware that this might call your `onCheckedChanged` listeners and could bring unexpected outcomes. But there is a work around for the resulting problem.

```
// Nullify listener
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

// Clear selection
holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();

// Reset listener after selection has been cleared
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
```

You can do this in kotlin

Comment: but i'm not using radio group, i'm using radio button inside recyclerview

Comment: Is it a single RadioButton, if multiple, you can enclose your RadioButtons in RadioGroup, if its single you could do the sameor implement a `radioButton.setChecked(false);` in the `holder`